# how to get this code to ask for the record insertion only once in python-mysql interface

Tags: python, mysql

```
import mysql.connector as myc
from mysql.connector import Error

def new():    
    idtype=input("Type of Id proof present=") 
    idno=input("Identification number=")
    name=input("Name of patient=")
    age=input("Age=")
    sex=input("Sex=")
    address=input("Address=")
    contactno=int(input("Contact Number="))
    date=input("Date =")
    doccons=input("Doctor consulted=")
    reason=input("Consultation reason=")
    dept=input("Department of doctor consulted=")
    aller=input("Medical Allergies (if any)=")
    insu=input("Availing Insurance=")
    temp=input("Temperature of patient(degree celsius)=")
    fees=int(input("Fees="))
    if True:
        db = myc.connect(host='localhost',
                         database='patients',
                         user='root',
                         password='root')
        mc = db.cursor()
        query = """INSERT INTO patient ( IDTYPE,IDNO,NAME,AGE,SEX,ADDRESS,CONTACT_NO,DATE,DOCTOR_CONSULTED,CONSULTATION_REASON,DEPARTMENT,ALLERGIES,INSURANCE,TEMPERATURE,FEES)    
                              VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) """

        recordTuple = (idtype,idno,name,age,sex,address,contactno,date,doccons,reason,dept,aller,insu,temp,fees)
        mc.execute(query, recordTuple)
        mc.execute("CREATE TABLE "+name+" (NAME VARCHAR(100),CONSULTED_DATE DATE,CONSULTATION_REASON VARCHAR(100),CONSULTED_DOCTOR VARCHAR(100),FEES VARCHAR(100))")
        qu="""INSERT INTO """+name+""" (NAME ,CONSULTED_DATE ,CONSULTATION_REASON ,CONSULTED_DOCTOR ,FEES )
                              VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
        retu=(name,date,reason,doccons,fees)
        mc.execute(qu,retu)
        db.commit()
        print("Record inserted successfully into Patient table")

    elif myc.Error==error:
        print("Failed to insert into MySQL table {}".format(error))

    else:
        if (db.is_connected()):      
            mc.close()
            db.close()
            print("MySQL connection is closed")
    return    
   
new()
```

this is the code I made for a school project. this is a module in a library. the problem is that: when I run the module as such it will ask for only one record insertion but when I call this module in another program it is asking for two records insertions. but I want to give only one record.

Any answers will be highly appreciated.
thank you.

Comment: can you check if the Database Schema is AutoIncrement on the place where you get the error... for IDTYPE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load this module from another module and then call `new()`, you are forgetting that the module itself contains a call to `new()` as the last line. So that makes two calls to `new()` in total. You want to modify your module to replace the last line to be instead:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    new()
```

When you run the file with the Python command, `__name__` will be '__main__' and therefore `new()` will be called. But when it is loaded with an *import* from another program or module, the above if condition will be False.

Comment: Thank you very much. @Booboo. it worked perfectly. ur help highly appreciated

Comment: ya, I am sorry. actually I am new to this site.. and thanks again